# ¿Cómo comparar cantidades de columnas entre dos tablas en SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dificultades para poder comparar la cantidad de campos o columnas de dos tablas que se encuentran en distintas Base de Datos. Ambas tablas tienen el mismo nombre y estructura, pero al ser más de 200 columnas necesito asegurarme que todas estén para poder trasladar información entre ellas, de modo que hice una consulta que les indico más abajo, pero me sale error de sintaxis en el uso del `count`. Espero me puedan ayudar en base al código que les muestro.

```
select
    case when COUNT(t1.*)=COUNT(t2.*) then '=' else 'distinto' end Numero
from BD_1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t1, 
     BD_2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t2
where t1.TABLE_NAME='MiTabla' and t2.TABLE_NAME='MiTabla'
```

No vi necesaria una vinculación tipo `INNER JOIN`o algo por estilo debido a que solo necesito saber la cantidad de columnas de ambas tablas y si coinciden o no.

Comment: En sql-server es posible hacer una consulta entre dos bases de datos distintas?, al parecer tu consulta esta bien, te muestra algun error?

Comment: Si se puede hacer consultas entre 2 bases de datos distintas. Es más, casi siempre tienes esos casos. Me sale un error de sintaxis cuando uso el `count` (mal usado)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo más sencillo sería que hicieras la agrupación **antes** de hace el join entre tablas.

También te recomiendo que siempres uses joins explícitos en vez de implícitos:

```
SELECT  t1.TABLE_NAME,
        CASE 
            WHEN t1.Columnas = t2.Columnas THEN '=' 
            ELSE 'distinto'
        END Numero
FROM (  SELECT TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) Columnas
        FROM BD_1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        GROUP BY TABLE_NAME) t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) Columnas
            FROM BD_1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            GROUP BY TABLE_NAME) t2
    ON t1.TABLE_NAME = t2.TABLE_NAME
WHERE t1.TABLE_NAME  = 'MiTabla';
```

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió, no sabía que una consulta "select... from..." funcionara como una "tabla", jamás se me hubiese ocurrido.

Cuando dices Joins implícitos ¿Te refieres cuando se ponen las dos tablas separadas solo por una coma?

Comment: @Fran.J sí, se puede en todos los motores de bases de datos. Cuando se usan así, se llama "tabla derivada"